# How to move one element to the right of another using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-float, move

I am trying to move one element next to another on my site.

[image]

Basically, I want the cart button to the right of quantity. `float: right` takes the button to the right place horizontally. But I also want to move them adjacent to each other.

Comment: what happens when you use float:left or even, display:inline or inline-block

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.quantity` is a block element (it takes the full row), so you can use `float` like this:

```
.quantity {float: left;}
```

Don't forget to `clear:both;` after if your floated elements start dropping out of their parent element (and they will unless there's a non-floated element that's higher than all of them).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the container of the number choosing element to

```
float: left;
```

and the button to

```
display: inline;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v7ryN/

Answer (score 0):

try using `position:relative;margin-right:10em` depending on your width scale. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use table in HTML and then Add the cart button and Quantity in different column within same row.

Answer (score 0):

Change HTML to this:

```
<div class="quantity buttons_added"><input type="button" value="-" class="minus" style="float: left;
"><input type="number" step="1" min="1" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" style="float: left;
"><input type="button" value="+" class="plus" style="float: left;
"><button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" style="float: left;">Add to cart</button>
</div>
```

Change CSS to this:

```
.quantity {
width: auto;
margin-bottom: .5em;
}
.single_add_to_cart_button {
margin-top: 1%;
margin-left: 3%;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 120px;
}
```

I've checked this. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the button element with `display:inline;` and input element with `float:left;`. You may try with this Solution.

```
input-field-name {
   float:left;
}

add-cart-button-name {
   display: inline;
}
```